# Create Google Cloud Function using API in Python

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-api-python-client

I'm working on a project with Python(3.6) & Django(1.10) in which I need to create a function at Google cloud using API request.

Here's what I have tried:

From **views.py** :

```
        try:
           auth = views.getauth()
           # Prepare Request Body
           req_body = {
               "CloudFunction": {
                   "name": func_obj.fname,
                   "entryPoint": func_obj.entryPoint,
                   "timeout": '60s',
                   "availableMemoryMb": func_obj.fmemory,
                   "sourceArchiveUrl": func_obj.sc_github,
                   },
                "sourceUploadUrl": func_obj.bucket,
                }
                service = discovery.build('cloudfunctions', 'v1beta2', http=auth, cachce_dicovery=False)
                func_req = service.projects().locations().functions().create(location='projects/' + func_obj.project
                                                                                      + '/locations/-',
                                                                             body=req_body)
                func_res = func_req.execute()
                print(func_res)
                return HttpResponse('Submitted',)
            except:
                return HttpResponse(status=500)
```

It returns 500 status response only,

is there something wrong with my request?
Help me, please!
Thanks in advance!